# How to concat a string to a variable in pl/sql(oracle function)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a function that outputs non-english words in a string but i am getting the following error:

```
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "|" when expecting one of the
         following:
         := . ( @ % ;
         The symbol ":= was inserted before "|" to continue.
```

The code that gives the error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function 
-- ...
IS
s varchar2(38);
lang varchar2(100);

begin
    s := -- ...
    lang := -- ...
    lang || s; -- trying to concate here

end;
```

The concatenation operator seems not to be working. Can anyone point out any mistake I'm making.

Comment: should be,  lang := lang || s;

Comment: Thanks that worked! Now i am getting another error: Encountered the symbol "IS".Would be helpfull if you could point me the way.

Comment: That is a different question. So please ask a new question.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I turned your comment into an answer. If you want to create your own answer please let me know, so I can delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

As OldProgrammer wrote in a comment:

```
lang || s
```

should be

```
lang := lang || s
```

Comment: There are more errors than that.

Comment: I know, but Stackoverflow isn't for "Please fix my code" type of questions. If we interpret the question as such, we should close (and delete) it.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are:

- `RETURN VARCHAR2` and not `RETURN string`
- `REGEXP_LIKE` returns a boolean and not a string.
- `lang || s;` should be `lang := lang || s;`

Which would give you the code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE Function findAssamese(
  string IN varchar2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  s varchar2(38);
  lang varchar2(100);
begin
  for i in 1..length(string) loop
    s := Substr(string,i,1);
    if REGEXP_LIKE (s, '[A-Z]') OR REGEXP_LIKE (s, '[a-z]') then
      lang := lang || s; -- trying to concate here
    end if;
  end loop;
  return lang;
end;
/
```

However, you could simply write:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE Function findAssamese(
  string IN varchar2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
begin
  return REGEXP_REPLACE(string, '[^A-Z]', NULL, 1, 0, 'i');
end;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fb1f0f4a2bd0b9a0f016a7a21c33b526)*

Comment: Thank you, with a few changes i was able to achieve what i wanted to do.